# How to select two or more elements with the same class in LESS?

Tags: css, less

Is there a short form in LESS to select two or more different elements with the same classes?

For example instead of writing `input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty, textarea.ng-invalid.ng-dirty, button.ng-invalid.ng-dirty` how could I write this shorter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
input, textarea, button {
    &.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {

    }
}
```

Where [`&` represents the current selector parent](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules). In other words, you are not selecting descendants, but rather elements with the classes `.ng-invalid.ng-dirty`. (i.e., `input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty`..)